# Is there a function in mongo to find if an element exists in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query such that a particular string does not exist in the array. My schema is:

```json
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
    meta: {
        user_likes: {
            type: [String],
        },
        user_dislikes: {
            type: [String],
        },
        user_liked_by: {
            type: [String],
        },
        user_matches: {
            type: [String],
        },
    ...
    },
```

The contents of the arrays in the `meta` object in the `_id` key of other documents, which is of type `String`.

Now I have an API endpoint to handle this query which is something like this:

```js
router.post('/fetchUsersForClient', async function (req, res) {
    /* Body
    {
        "client_id" : String
    }
    */
    try {
            var client_id = req.body.client_id;
            const users = await SampleUser.find(); //query here
            res.json(users);
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({ message: error });
    }
});
```

I want to write a query such that the variable `client_id` does not exist in any of the arrays in the `meta` object and `client_id` is not equal to `_id` of any document.

EDIT: I tried using this query to get my results, but I do not know how to replace `"1"` in the query.

```json
{
    "_id" : {
        $ne : "1"
    },
    $and : [
        {
            "meta.user_likes" : {
                $not : /.*1.*/i
            }
        },
        {
            "meta.user_dislikes" : {
                $not : /.*1.*/i
            }
        },
        {
            "meta.user_matches" : {
                $not : /.*1.*/i
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: just try `{ "_id": { $ne: client_id }, "meta.client_id": { $ne: client_id } }`

Comment: @turivishal its not working, I think because there is no `client_id` in `meta` object

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this problem by modifying the code given about a bit. Here I used a separate constant to initialise a regex pattern.
Here is my approach:

```js
router.post('/fetchUsersForClient', async function (req, res) {
    /* Body
    {
        "client_id" : String
    }
    */
    try {
            var client_id = req.body.client_id;
            var expr = '.*var.*'
            expr = expr.replace("var", client_id);
            const chkExp = new RegExp(expr);
            const users = await User.find(
                {
                    "_id": {
                        $ne: client_id
                    },
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "meta.user_likes": {
                                $not: chkExp
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "meta.user_liked_by": {
                                $not: chkExp
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "meta.user_dislikes": {
                                $not: chkExp
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "meta.user_matches": {
                                $not: chkExp
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );
            res.json(users);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send({ message: error });
    }
});
```